# Python replacing parts of string

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm having trouble writing a python function `replace_str` that consumes 3 non-empty strings, base, target and rep.

The first string, `base` represents a base string that you want to update. The second string `target` represents the target string that you want to replace and the third string `rep` represents a string that will replace the target in the updated string.

The function produces a new string in which the `target` string is replaced by the `rep` string in the `base` string, but produces the same `base` string if either of the following conditions hold true.

• If the `target` string is not found in the `base` string or,

• If the `target` and `rep` are the same strings.

NOT allowed to use the string methods `replace` and `find`

This is what I have so far:

`def replace_str(base, target, rep):
    m = 0
    n = len(target)
    if base[m:n] == target:
        new_base = base[0:m] + rep + base[n:]
        return replace_str(new_base, target, rep)
    else:
        m = m + 1
        n = n + 1
        return replace_str(base, target, rep)`

Comment: You should show your code and people will be happy to correct you. Without seeing what you've done, it seems like you're asking people to do your work for you and since it smells like homework people people will be less inclined to offer help.

Comment: I totally understand but I have no idea where to start this. If I had some general idea I could work on from there

Comment: One approach is to write it as if you could use `replace` and `find`. Then implement your own `replace` and `find`. I don't understand why they teach python like this though. It seems to defy the way the language is used to put these limitations in place.

Comment: read tower of Hanoi algorithm.

Comment: I added an example of what I've done so far

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `split`, why not something like this :

```
"rep".join("target1 other string target2".split("target"))
```

The `split` method returns a list of elements delimited by the target. `join` does the opposite : it constructs a string from a list by inserting a string between each element.

You can see the documentation here for those functions :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join